# How to display all user details in labels from the database when a user logs in with only user name and password [C# Windows Form application]

Tags: c#

Currently developing a delivery system and I want the customer's details to be shown in `labels` in C# form application.
A user will log only with username and password. But I want to display their,

- name
- ID
- Address
- Contact
- Password

all of these are in the database. But I cannot figure out how to display only the data of that specific user who is logged in at the moment.

Comment: How are you accessing the DataBase? Is "Customers" a class?

Comment: Which DB are you using? 
You could do it by simple select queries where the username matches that info inside your table.